# Как загружать статьи из mysql через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Допустим есть бд в которой мои статьи..
На главную страницу при загрузке выводится 10 статей..
В конце страници есть кнопка "загрузить еще", и вот нужно чтоб при нажатии на эту кнопку на страницу загрузились следующие записи без  перезагрузки страници, но при этом нужно чтобы и первые 10 записей остались...
Типа как лента в вк, гортаешь новости и когда быстро проматал вниз автоматически загружаются остальные записи но предидущие не пропадают...такая себе бесконечная лента..
Мне нужно тоже самое только без автозагрузки, а чтобы загрузка следующих 10 постов произошла по нажатию на кнопку...
Кто может привести пример как это роботает...?
Буду благодарен за пример кода...

Comment: Что уже сделано?

Comment: Ну так вам прямая дорога к `AJAX` запросу. Делаете кнопку, `onclick = "showMoreArticles()"`. И пишете функцию, которая будет делать `AJAX` запрос на сервак, на котором вы подготавливаете к выводу `html` с 10 статьями. Вот и всё. А по `succsess` в блок с вашими статьями добавляете статьи из ответа.

Comment: Мне тоже интерестно, как подготовить html в PHP для выброса в аякс? Остальное понятно.

Comment: Вот нашол сам решение... Если комуто еще пригодится
> http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/127-dinamicheskaja_podgruzka_dannyh_na_stranicu.html

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример Аякса

```
 $('#yourbutton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'item.php',
        dataType: "JSON",
        success(data){
                var items='';
                items='<div><h1>Привет я новая статья</h1><br><h2>я добавилась</h2>';
                for(var item in data){
                    '<p>'+data[item]+'</p><br>';
                }
                items+='</div>';
                $('.moreitems').html(items);
        }
    })
});
```

Вот пример PHP

```
$item=['Я первая статья','Я вторая статья','А я тут третъя','Ну и так далее'];
echo json_encode($item);
```